# IntelliJ missing all inspections

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, inspections

I'm having an issue with IntelliJ, that I cannot seem to find a solution for myself. I have not changed any settings, yet when I started my IDE this morning, all Inspections and other highlighting has disappeared.

By highlighting, I mean stuff like variable names becoming purple, static finals shown with italic text, etc.

Inheritance seems to be broken as well, in that an implementing method links to the implemented interface method, but interface methods do not link to the implementing method.

My search for this tells me that there is an icon for this in the bottom right. That's set to "Inspections", and under configuration, it seems like everything is set to default.

Is there some way to un-break my IDE?

Comment: Please check that File | Power save mode is not enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (or at least one) answer to this is:

File -> Invalidate Caches

Answer (score 13):

Another solution:

File -> Power Save mode

It needs to be disabled.

Comment: This would most probably be the culprit if Java keywords are highlighted but other elements like fields, Classes and methods are not highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the folder the code is in is marked as the sources root. If it's not marked as the sources root, syntax highlighting will be very limited.

To mark a directory as the sources root, right click the directory, then navigate down to "Mark directory as" and select "Sources root."

[image: I spent an embarrassingly long time trying to figure out what was wrong. Don't judge me. Thought it might save someone else some time to post this.]